# How to disable MoPub AdPlacer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mopub

I'm using MoPub Native Ads and have integrated using their MPTableViewAdPlacer.

Initializing the ad placer is very simple -

```
self.adPlacer = [MPTableViewAdPlacer placerWithTableView:self.tableView
                                  viewController:self
                         defaultAdRenderingClass:[SomeTableViewAdCell class]];
...
[self.adPlacer loadAdsForAdUnitID:@"mopub_ad_unit_id"];
```

The app this is integrated in has a single view, so the tableview is only created once on launch. I'd like to be able to disable the ad placer after it's been initialized. For example, for an in app purchase to disable the ads.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'd like to do the same thing. You can answer your own question if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue that let premium user has no ad in our app.

I found that you may change the `adUnitID` as `nil` if user has purchased for no ad.

I also found the Mopub support team has replied in their forum.
https://twittercommunity.com/t/disable-mopub-ad-placer/63127/2

you may change the ad keyword to get ad or get no ad.